# Easiest way to update TextView or String from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

It know this is possible in multiple ways like with bundles, params... But what is the shortest easiest way to update a textview or string data from an AsyncTask's OnPostExecute method?

Comment: Need to describe more. Do you want to update textview text from service call?

Comment: No I want to update it when the AsyncTask finishes. I found some examples, but those have AsyncTask inside the Activity.class file, I have it as a seprate class as I need to to get general data with which I can update textViews in multiple fragments.

Comment: updating textView require UI thread regardless if you need to use AsyncTask or not.

Comment: @Tachanka then pass the View in your `AsyncTask` subclass constructor as `WeakReference`.

Comment: You can solve it in many ways. You can create interface. For example A simple solution may be create a static function/functions for where you need update and call that function when OnPostExecute done.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easiest way to update your view components is, 
you need to set your view components and class members in either your class or in `AsyncTask`.
After finishing grabbing data from server or processing, in `AsyncTask` `OnPostExecute` function, you can directly manipulate your members, e.g,

`TextView.setText(your string here).`